# Is battery a capacitor that's being continuously charged?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, voltage, capacitance, batteries

Is it correct to say that a battery is like a capacitor which keeps being charged?

Comment: Charcged by what? By another battery? No, it is a pump with a tank of a fuel.

Comment: By the chemical reactions within it..?

Comment: Depends on how strict your threshold for the word “like” is.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say so, no.

- Firstly, the key difference between a capacitor and a typical battery is the state in which the energy is stored. A capacitor is the only device that can be said to store "electricity", meaning what is being stored is the actual charges and charge separation on two plates. In a battery, the energy content is stored *chemically* in potential chemical energy which is then spent to separate charges from atoms and accumulating this charge on the terminals. This storage mechanism is a key difference since it involves more energy transformation steps and thus a different perspective on loss efficiencly.
- Secondly, the capacitor works via having two separated plates in very close vicinity. The two terminals of a battery cannot be considered close. Meaning, the charge induction due to the opposite plate does not happen in a battery (it does not happen due to electric induction).
- Thirdly, and somewhat derived from the first point, the voltage that a capacitor can provide is *linear* whereas it from a battery is *constant* (within its operating range). This is due to the gradual decrease in charge of the capacitor plates as energy is drawn from it, which does not happen from the battery terminals as long as it still contains chemical energy.

Comment: Ok, I understand they work in a different manner. My point is, that both battery and capacitor supply current because there is one terminal that has an accumulation of positive charge, and another terminal with accumulation of negative charge. Is it so?

Comment: @YoavKlein Sure, both work via having two oppositely charged plates. But they work in very different ways and provide different effects as described. The category of devices that can supply electric energy in this manner is as a whole called **voltage sources**. A capacitor and a battery are two types of voltage sources. I would rather say that they are siblings and two different types for different applications than that one is a special type of the other.

Comment: @Steeven, your third bullet point "...voltage..." Should be the first: A battery _behaves_ differently from a capacitor. It obeys a different mathematical law. A capacitor obeys a simple law, $V=\frac{1}{C}\int idt$—Voltage is the integral of current with respect to time, divided by the _capacitance._ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Current%E2%80%93voltage_relation). A battery behaves, as you said, kind of like a [voltage source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source), but with several complications that are different depending on the battery chemistry, size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that a battery is like a capacitor which keeps
> being charged?

Not really.

When a (rechargeable) battery is being charged it converts electrical potential energy from the electrical charging source to chemical potential energy which is stored in the battery and made available to convert back to electrical potential energy when connected to a circuit.

A capacitor only stores electrical potential which is generally far less than the chemical potential energy stored in a battery. When it is charged the charging source stores electrical potential energy in the capacitor.

Hope this helps.